# Unable to open database in Android Pie (Android 9)

Tags: database, sqlite, release, android-9.0-pie

I used checkDataBase function to ensure if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application in Oreo. But in Android Pie it is not working.

```
private boolean checkDataBase (String dbName, int dbVersion) {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {

        String myPath = DB_PATH + dbName;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_ABORT);

        if (checkDB.getVersion() < dbVersion) {
            Timber.d("Delete database called");
            myContext.deleteDatabase(dbName);
            return false;
        }
    } catch(SQLiteException e) {

    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null;
}
```

> Getting this error: os_unix.c:36667: (2) open(/data/data/my.androidPieTrial.app/databases/admin.db) 
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database

Answer (score 12):

I got the solution. In Android Oreo and below version, the way i am accessing db works fine but in Android Pie it wasn't working.This is the way to handle it in Android Pie.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        MySQLiteOpenHelper helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper();
        SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        myPath = database.getPath();

    } else {
        String DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/my.trial.app/databases/";
        myPath = DB_PATH + dbName;
    }

    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    checkDB.disableWriteAheadLogging();
```

Comment: i have same problem 
so can u please help me to sort out this issue
i cant understand what u r saying in this code snippet  
can u please more explain

Comment: @APOORVADOSHI basically instead of using a hard coded path based upon the Environment.getDataDirectory for Pie an improved (get the path via the system) method is being used. However really the correct way is to use `context.getDatabasePath(the_database_name).getAbsolutePath();` (which has been available since API 1 and thus works with all versions).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can you please share the MySQLiteOpenHelper class, because otherwise, its really unclear how to fix the issue .

Comment: this worked for me but an important part was using: checkDB.disableWriteAheadLogging();

Comment: I am also having same issue but its not working for me

Comment: I am using SQLiteAssetHelper and getting NullPointerException when trying to open the database for the first time. The database doesn't get copied from the asset folder.

Answer (score 4):

Override following method on SQLiteOpenHelper class for android PIE OS version.

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
context.getDatabasePath(the_database_name).getPath();
```

Works fine since `getDatabasePath()` returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a database created. Works for all version of android