# Reading a Db in Pie

Tags: android, sqlite

So, I recently migrated to a Oneplus 6t running on Android 9.0 
I had a DB file with me which I read and write to my current application DB.
I checked using the SqliteManager that all the data is intact and correct. The queries are working fine too.
The problem is the application cant seem to fetch data from the DB. The cursor is always empty and there is no error in logs related to the Database.
The same file when imported in another phone is working fine (although that phone is on android 8.1). 
Can anyone suggest me anything how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe this will be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930153/unable-to-open-database-in-android-pie-android-9

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your **SQLiteOpenHelper** class.This should work for pie

```
        @Override
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
        }
```