# How to openDatabase at external SD card in Android P ( API 28 )

Tags: android, android-sqlite

How to openDatabase at external SD card in Android P (API 28)?

The code is over here :
[Unable to open database in Android Pie (Android 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930153/unable-to-open-database-in-android-pie-android-9)

The Android P(API 28) is not valid for SQLite Database files that are located in a custom path in external SD card.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    MySQLiteOpenHelper helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper();
    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    myPath = database.getPath();
} else {
    String DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/my.trial.app/databases/";  
    myPath = DB_PATH + dbName;
}
checkDB=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
checkDB.disableWriteAheadLogging();
```

I want a method that is similar to:

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(custom_path, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
```

Comment: Check @MikeT answer in that post.

Comment: @adel is your issue solved. Were you able to load the database in Android Pie?